# Accurate hiking maps of Austria

Tags: hiking, maps, austria

I'm going to Austria for hiking. In Switzerland, we have very accurate maps that are available [online for free](http://map.geo.admin.ch/). Is there anything similar for Austria? I couldn't find a central place that covers whole Austria and includes all the information that the Swiss maps include: I would be especially interested in colored terrain that is more than 30° steep and populations of alpine ibex.

Comment: By “capricorn” do you mean “wild goats”?

Comment: Or maybe [Alpine ibex (steinbock)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_ibex)

Comment: Have you give a try to Open Stret Maps or Garmin ones? They are not as good as the Switzerland maps you have, but are similar (without colors)

Comment: @Relaxed and drat you're right, it should be alpine ibex.

Comment: @drat Alpine ibex is simply a species of wild goat ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you search for the terms "wanderkarte" and "österreich", you can find those online:

- [Bergfex](http://www.bergfex.at/sommer/oesterreich/touren/) has height meters, height profiles etc.
- [maps.wandern.at](http://maps.wandern.at) has even more information such as lengthy descriptions and photos.

And [here is a blog](http://www.gipfeltreffen.at/archive/index.php/t-48765.html) where people list sightings of Ibex in Austria frmo 2010-2013.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the best map is produced by the Federal Office of Metrology and Surveying (BEV - Bundesamt für Eich und vermessungswesen). They produce the so called OeK50 and OeK25 (austrian map - Oestereichische Karte in scale 1:50000 or 1:25000).

Unfortunately the print version can be rather expensive at 7EUR per part, but if you know which ones you need it is ok.

The online version is free, and they have an online shop. I think the Alpenverein mentioned before sells this map as well.

http://www.austrianmap.at/amap/index.php?SKN=1&XPX=637&YPX=492

Answer (score 2):

Kompass are great: http://www.kompass.de/touren-und-regionen/touren/

Switch layer to Summer/Winter in top right to see the details like marked trails and contours (otherwise it shows Open Street Map with less details). There are even winter ski tours there.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend https://www.alpenvereinaktiv.com/
There is also an app for that - for free: https://www.alpenvereinaktiv.com/de/mobile-app.html

Answer (score 1):

With the exception of the excellent BEV maps and their mediocre web-interface, all the previous answers are maps based on [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/). Therefore, they are unlikely to differ in accuracy/level of detail. In my opinion [OpenTopoMap](https://opentopomap.org/) is the best OSM-based map, as it has a clean interface without distractions and includes elevation-information.